# Which Nifi processor to use for RDBMS Extract

Tags: apache-nifi

i will explain my use case to understand which DB extract utility to use.

1. I need to extract data from SQL Server tables with varying frequency each day. Each extract query is a complex SQL statement, involving 5-10 tables in joins etc with multiple causes. Have around 20-30 such statements overall.
2. All these extract queries might be required to run multiple times a day with varying frequencies each day. It depends on how many times we receive data from source system or other cases.
3. We are planning to use Kafka to publish a message to let Nifi workflow know whenever a RDBMS table is updated and flow needs to be triggered (i can't just trigger Nifi flow based on "incremental" column value, there might only be all row update scenarios and we might not create new rows in tables).

How should i go about designing my Nifi. There are ExecuteSQL/GenerateTableFetch/ExecuteSQLRecord/QueryDatabaseTable all sorts of components available. Which one is going to fit my requirement best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting that you use ExecuteSQL. You can set query from attribute or compose it using attribute. Easiest way is to create json and then parse that json and create attributes. Check this example,  here is sql created from file you can adjust it to create it from kafka [link](https://codeload.github.com/gist/6d2bbfe48809e036008153f15113ab80/zip/12b3cc62f3b9932d16e619351a3efd033ca3fabf)
[image]